# How to get all events of the user on Calendar of Moodle?

Tags: moodle

Calendar of Moodle can show all events of the user's own. 
I want a feature like as : I'm a web admin of a Moodle site and I want to get all events, detail all events of the user.

How to get all events of the user on Calendar of Moodle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the function `calendar_get_events` parsing in the ID of your user as the third parameter and `false` for the forth and fifth parameters.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Calendar_API#Retrieve_calendar_event_information

Comment: Have you any idea about getting calendar events using of Moodle Web Services API `core_calendar_get_calendar_events` for external programs?

Comment: @Dozent That's not supported with the web service function, you'll need to write a plugin and add a new web service function yourself